# Can IList<IWebElement> work with PageObject?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, pageobjects

I have a simple loop that click test a list.

The loop works smooth, but I wonder if its possible to use Page-object? 
I cant seem to find if someone else have done it. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have

```
public SeleniumPage ClickLink()
{
   IList<IWebElement> Items= PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElements(By.
                       XPath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li"));
   foreach (IWebElement Item in Items)
   {
      Item.ChinsayClick();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }
   return new SeleniumPage();
}
```

But would rather have something like this.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li")]
public IWebElement List { get; set; }

public SeleniumPage ClickLink()
{
   IList<IWebElement> Items= List;
   foreach (IWebElement Item in Items)
   {
      Item.ChinsayClick();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }
   return new SeleniumPage();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: well... that i asked before i noticed that this was quite simple to fix =/
Will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a simple answer to this, So I will answer my own question if it could help some body else.

We can add IList directly to the PageObject as

```
Public IList<IWebElement>
```

And then just call it from the loop `(IWebElement List in Lists)`

Solution :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li")]
public IList<IWebElement> Lists { get; set; }

public SeleniumPage()
{
    foreach (IWebElement List in Lists)
    {
        List.ChinsayClick();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    return new SeleniumPage();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer so the question gets marked as answered.